# Causing Null Pointer Exception Error in specific device only

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'am getting Null Pointer Exception errors in specific devices only, they are,

VIBE K6 Note (K53a48) , VIBE K6 Power (K33a42) , VIBE K6 (K33a48) , P2 (P2a42).

They are all working in the android V 7.0 exactly.

I know this question is already asked but i'm assuming why these specific devices only cause problems, is that error in my code or in OS of that devices ?

Please help me to solve this problem - Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService (ActivityThread.java:3344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap27 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1570)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6077)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.cambarkro.nightmode.services.Darkness.onDestroy (Darkness.java:107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService (ActivityThread.java:3327)
```

Error Line:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        wm.removeView(myView);

        if (mNotifyManager != null) {
            mNotifyManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

Link for my app in Playstore:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cambarkro.nightmode&hl=en

Crash Report Image:
[Here you can see errors are caused by specific devices only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyull.png)

Comment: `Error Line:` show the line please. What is `Darkness.java:107`

Comment: See my question there i already mentioned my error Darkness.java:107 as (error line:) and exact line is : wm.removeView(myView);

Comment: see my comment, I already mentioned that I saw that your error is at `Darkness.java:107`. But nobody except you knows what is that line. That's why I asked to `show the line please`

Comment: for me it is not clear why you remove some view in onDestoy at all, as it makes no sense. To fix the error you may just wrap this line into the null check. that devices may handle <whatever> destroy another way

Comment: **Error Line:** 4th line -  wm.removeView(myView);